# MS SQL: How to separate out records which have no childs in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a tricky problem. I have a very complex view in MS SQL 2005 with the following result:

```
|  ID  |   Name   |  ParentID  |
--------------------------------
|  1   |   Cars   |     1      |
|  2   |   Audi   |     1      |
|  3   |  Toyota  |     1      |
|  4   |  Trucks  |     4      |
```

Now I want my view to recognize that the record with ID 4 has no children and, because of this, to separate it out.

Any ideas? ;)

Thanks
Torben

Comment: This row which do not have a parent, are they always referencing itself?

Comment: Yes, they are. But the problem is, that the first row always referencing itself. And this is only a basic example with two levels, there can also be four or five levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would would be the ones which have no children:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM theView a
    LEFT JOIN theView b ON (a.a = b.ParentId AND b.Id <> b.ParentId)
WHERE b.Id IS NULL
```

However ID 2 and ID 3 are without children as well.

Comment: I see ... the only way to solve the problem would be a new view, which joines the first view with itself. Thank you.

Comment: Torben H. Please don't write views that reference views! Write a stored proc or something instead. Views referencing views are performance killers (you can't index a view that refernces another view) and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ParentID = ID` for the Parent rows, you want to find the ones where there's only *one* instance of a given ParentID:

```
SELECT
   ParentID
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   ParentID
HAVING
   COUNT(1) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ParentID NOT IN (SELECT     ParentID 
                 FROM       TABLE 
                 WHERE      ParentID <> ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as parent
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT child.ParentID 
  FROM   Table as child
  WHERE  parent.ParentId = child.id
    and parent.id != child.id
)
```

If the rows without parent aways reference itself, it's easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as parent
WHERE parent.parentId != parent.id
```

Comment: See my comment. :) The first rows also referencing itself, but shouldn't be sort out.